# Openpyxl comparing values in two sheets to see if a value does not exist

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am making an excel comparing program that takes  a certain amount of sheets, compares them and checks to see if the values in one of the sheets do not exist in the other. However, I am receiving a repetitive problem. To clarify, here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import openpyxl, os, csv
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string

# Output File
outputFile = open('output.csv','w',newline='')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)

# Tk initialization for file dialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Number of sheets to be compared
number = input('Enter number of workbook sheets for comparison: ')
number = int(number)

# Functions for generating file paths
def generate_file_path():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open Workbook")
    return file_path

# Variables to store file paths, workbooks and worksheets
all_ws = []

# Core function for program's logistics
def core():
    # for loops for generating file paths, workbooks and worsheets
    for x in range(number):
        path = generate_file_path()
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
        ws = wb['CBF']
        all_ws.append(ws)

    # for loop to use for finding diff
    for row in all_ws[1].iter_cols():
        for cellz in row:
            sheet_cols.append(cellz.value)

    # loop that checks if the value does not exist
    for ws_diff in range(number):
        for row,row2 in zip(all_ws[0].iter_cols(),all_ws[1].iter_cols()):
            for cell,cell2 in zip(row,row2):
                if cell.value not in sheet_cols:
                    outputWriter.writerow([str(cell2.value)])
```

However, when I check my csv file, the "differences" outputted appear to be on both of the files. Does anyone have any suggestions for helping me out? Anything would be great thank you

Comment: What's with `[number-number]` and `[number-number+1]` – did you mean to use `ws_diff` in there somewhere? Also you have three `for` loops which look like they could be combined into one.

Comment: @miken32 updated my question now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could do this:

1. Change: `for row in all_ws[1].iter_cols():`

   To: `for row in all_ws[0].iter_cols():`
2. After that:

Change `if cell.value not in sheet_cols:`

To:  `if cell2.value in sheet_cols:`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You don't change anything in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to stay as close to the source code you provided as possible, taking only a few liberties. The biggest changes I made were adding more columns to the csv output and adding the ability to tell the core function whether you care about the location of the cell or not; whether you are -

1.) comparing each cell of every worksheet after the first against the value of that exact cell coordinate in the first worksheet (location_matters=True)

or whether you are

2.) comparing each cell of every worksheet after the first against every value found in the first worksheet selected (location_matters=False)

Here's the modified code I came up with:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import openpyxl, os, csv
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string

# Output File
outputFile = open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
outputWriter.writerow(["Worksheet Number", "Value Not Found", "Location of Cell"])  # add columns

# Tk initialization for file dialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Number of sheets to be compared
number = input('Enter number of workbook sheets for comparison: ')
number = int(number)

# Functions for generating file paths
def generate_file_path():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open Workbook")
    return file_path


# Variables to store file paths, workbooks and worksheets
all_ws = []


# Core function for program's logistics
def core(number_of_worksheets, location_matters=False):
    # for loops for generating file paths, workbooks and worsheets
    for x in range(number_of_worksheets):
        path = generate_file_path()
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
        ws = wb['CBF']
        all_ws.append(ws)
    root.destroy()  # destroy tk when you're done with it

    # for loop to use for loading first workbook's values into list
    sheet_cols = []
    for row in all_ws[0].iter_cols():  # using the 1st ws here instead of the 2nd
        for cellz in row:
            sheet_cols.append(cellz.value)

    # loop that checks if the value does not exist in first ws
    for ws_diff in range(1, number):
        for row, row2 in zip(all_ws[0].iter_cols(), all_ws[ws_diff].iter_cols()):
            for cell, cell2 in zip(row, row2):
                if location_matters:
                    if cell.value != cell2.value:
                        outputWriter.writerow([ws_diff, str(cell2.value), cell.coordinate])
                else:
                    if cell2.value not in sheet_cols:
                        outputWriter.writerow([ws_diff, str(cell2.value), "N/A"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    core(number_of_worksheets=number, location_matters=False)
```

Comment: no it still does  not work. It may be because of the file.